# Why does node.js's crypto module give a different result than Java's Cipher class for AES encryption?

Tags: java, node.js, encryption, aes

I'm trying to understand why encrypted data changes when using Java or Node.js to encrypt it, I need to adapt node.js code to make it return exactly the same encrypted data that I have on Java. (Note that I cannot modify the java snippet)

**Node.js Implementation:**

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

console.log("\n\n============");
var cKey = new Buffer("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA", "utf-8");
var cIv = new Buffer("1111111111111111", "utf-8");
var cData = "x";
console.log(cKey);
console.log(cIv);
console.log("UTF-8 Data: " + cData);

var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv("aes-256-cbc", cKey, cIv);
var cipherText = cipher.update(cData, 'utf8', 'hex') + cipher.final('hex');

console.log("Our data: " + cipherText);
```

The previous snippet will print the following result:

```
<Buffer 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41>
<Buffer 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31>
UTF-8 Data: x
Our data: 0eddfe1857248c7057904455d189cf31
```

**Java Implementation:**

```
byte[] key = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA".getBytes();
byte[] data = "x".getBytes();
byte[] iv = "1111111111111111".getBytes();
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES"), ivspec);
byte[] result = cipher.doFinal(data);
_print(result);
```

That snippet will print:

```
17b0ccd594229baa6dabd5e850e07fdf
```

Please note that I compared bytes for data, iv and key and those are exactly the same.

How can I modify node's snippet to make it return the same bytes of java's?

Comment: I think in java `AES` means `aes-128-cbc`. I guess key size does matter in getting the cypher text.

Comment: What is AesSymmetricKey? Where does this class come from and what does it do? What is the difference between if and initializationVector? And why does the Java code call EncryptionService.encryptAesData and then cipher.doFinal? Is there a reason or is that just a redundancy?

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to remove that, it's not part of this snippet.

Comment: That's still not your Java code. The Cipher.getInstance("AES") will give you AES/ECB/NOPADDING, and trying to init this with an IV will result in an InvalidAlgorithmParameterException being thrown.

Comment: @wallenborn Whether an exception will be thrown probably depends on the Java version/JVM/default JCE provider. That may be the case for your environment, but not necessarily true for OPs environement.

Comment: @Artjom B. That's of course possible. My comment referred to Oracle Java 7 in its standard setup. Luca might be using a different version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the same mode of operation. Your java code specifies the cipher string as "AES". This is not fully qualified, so your default JCE provider will select its own default for "AES" which is "AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding" (in your case), because it's the most basic one, but also insecure mode.

You need to use the same mode of operation in node.js. The only two things that you need to change are the IV size (ECB doesn't use an IV!) and the cipher string:

```
var cIv = new Buffer(0);
var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv("aes-256-ecb", cKey, cIv);
```

---

Please note that ECB mode is not semantically secure by itself. Also, the ciphertexts are not authenticated so you should be using either an encrypt-then-MAC scheme with HMAC-SHA256 or an authenticated mode like GCM or EAX.

Comment: `Cipher.getInstance("AES")` and `Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5padding")` is same.

Comment: @rakeb.void Yes, that's true for probably most JCE providers including the Sun JCE, but it doesn't have to be true for all. A JCE provider may decide to default to `Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5padding")` with an all zero IV or something like that. That's why it's always a good idea to use a fully qualified cipher string.

Answer (score 0):

Your node.js code looks like it's doing what it claims to be doing, as the following unit test succeeds:

```
@Test
public void testAes() throws InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
  byte[] key = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA".getBytes();
  byte[] data = "x".getBytes();
  byte[] iv = "1111111111111111".getBytes();
  Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
  IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
  cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES"), ivspec);
  byte[] result = cipher.doFinal(data);
  assertEquals("0eddfe1857248c7057904455d189cf31", DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(result).toLowerCase());
}
```

I suspect your Java code is not doing what it claims to be doing.